# Ctrl + D select in reverse

Tags: sublimetext2

Is there a way to do the reverse selection in Sublime Text 2?

I know that you can skip (`Ctrl + K, Ctrl + D`), undo (`Ctrl + Y`) and cherry pick (`hold alt`) your selection from `Ctrl + D` but how do I tell sublime to multi-select in reverse order?

Let's say, instead of going up to down, I want to go down to up.

Comment: This is not built-in, but the answer below contains a plugin that does the job.  You can put it in your `User` directory and then just assign a keyboard shortcut that does not conflict with another combination already assigned.  Call it anything when saving the file -- e.g., `inverse_find_under_expand.py`.  The keyboard shortcut goes into a user settings file -- e.g., `Default (OSX).sublime-keymap`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If anyone can please improve upon this plugin so that it scrolls the screen upwards as it selects, that would be greatly appreciated.

---

**NOTE**:  The OSX key binding that I chose for this example *conflicts* with `duplicate_line`, so that key binding would need to be commented out for this new key binding to work -- otherwise, select a different key binding that is not already taken.

```
{ "keys": ["super+shift+d"], "command": "inverse_find_under_expand" },
```

---

```py
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class InverseFindUnderExpandCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    "Add the previous occurrence of the word under the cursor to the selection"

    def run(self, edit):
        sel = [s for s in self.view.sel()]

        new_sel = []

        for s in sel:
            self.view.sel().clear()
            self.view.sel().add(s)

            self.view.window().run_command('find_under_prev')

            for ns in self.view.sel():
                new_sel.append(ns)

        self.view.sel().clear()

        for s in sel:
            self.view.sel().add(s)

        for s in new_sel:
            self.view.sel().add(s)
```

Comment: This is better than nothing. Thanks.

Comment: Nice solution. Thank you :)

Comment: This is epic! Thanks mate, appreciate it! 

Comment: Sometimes sublime doesn't scroll up when a previous selection is found. Is there a way to fix that? cheers!